# Are C# arrays thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, arrays, thread-safety

In particular

1. Create a function to take an array and an index as parameters.
2. Create a n element array.
3. Create a n count loop.
4. Inside the loop on a new thread assign a new instance of the object to the array using the indexer passed in.

I know how to manage the threads etc. I am interested in know if this is thread safe way of doing something.

```
 class Program
{
    // bogus object
    class SomeObject
    {
        private int value1;
        private int value2;

        public SomeObject(int value1, int value2)
        {
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var s = new SomeObject[10];
        var threads = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
        var stp = new SmartThreadPool(1000, threads, threads);
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            stp.QueueWorkItem(CreateElement, s, i);
        }

    }

    static void CreateElement(SomeObject[] s, int index)
    {
        s[index] = new SomeObject(index, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is utterly not to the point of the question, but I would advise against using `Environment.ProcessorCount - 1` - those poor single-core folks 'll be downright unhappy otherwise...

Comment: There are people with single-core processors?

Comment: @Gary there are virtual machines with "one" processor ;)

Comment: `Environment.ProcessorCount - 1` in this way is completely wrong. you MUST consider single-core CPUs. The proper is: `int threads = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1; if(threads==0) threads=1;`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I believe that if each thread only works on a separate part of the array, all will be well. If you're going to *share* data (i. e. communicate it between threads) then you'll need some sort of memory barrier to avoid memory model issues.

I *believe* that if you spawn a bunch of threads, each of which populates its own section of the array, then wait for all of those threads to finish using `Thread.Join`, that that will do enough in terms of barriers for you to be safe. I don't have any supporting documentation for that at the moment, mind you ...

EDIT: Your sample code is safe. At no time are two threads accessing the same element - it's as if they each have separate variables. However, that doesn't tend to be useful on its own. At some point normally the threads will want to share state - one thread will want to read what another has written. Otherwise there's no point in them writing into a shared array instead of into their own private variables. *That's* the point at which you need to be careful - the coordination between threads.

Comment: Array elements follow the same rules as regular variables, in that swapping a reference will be atomic but replacing a struct will generally not be.  This doesn't take into account the need for a memory barrier, though, to make accesses volatile.

As you said, whether it's safe is going to depend precisely on what the coder is doing.

Comment: @Steven: Yup, that was about my understanding :)

Comment: @Steven "whether it's safe is going to depend precisely on what the coder is doing." - Isn't that the same as saying "No, it's not safe." ?

Comment: Early Intel processors used exactly this strategy to multi-task (8086) - the lower 640kb was reserved for apps and the OS and the remainder for BIOS.  Later, hardware support for virtual address ranges (80286, protected mode) pacified the wild west coding of "let's all hack on one array".

If you are going to use this technique, do yourself a favor and make use of System.ArraySegment<T>.

Comment: @Rik: No, it's not the same. Thread safety should almost never be simplified to a "yes" or "no" answer.

Comment: In my use case after the array is created I will insert the data into the database, but that is another question.

Answer (score 21):

[MSDN documentation on Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) says:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic)
>   members of this type are thread safe.
>   Any instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> This implementation does not provide a
>   synchronized (thread safe) wrapper for
>   an Array; however, .NET Framework
>   classes based on Array provide their
>   own synchronized version of the
>   collection using the SyncRoot
>   property.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is
>   synchronized, other threads can still
>   modify the collection, which causes
>   the enumerator to throw an exception.
>   To guarantee thread safety during
>   enumeration, you can either lock the
>   collection during the entire
>   enumeration or catch the exceptions
>   resulting from changes made by other
>   threads.

So no, they're not thread safe.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I am not doing any enumeration how can this guy get 13 votes?

Comment: A vote means the answer is helpful. Your checkmark indicates than an answer solves your problem.  Given this information, if I were developing a threadable class with Arrays, I believe the first thing I would do is fire up Reflector, open up one of the Framework classes that uses Array in a thread-safe context, and see what they are doing with SyncRoot.

Comment: This answer is truly unhelpful, inasmuch as the MSDN quote is quite misleading *and* not to the point.  Array accesses to reference types are atomic; even enumerating over such an array (while probably unwise) is to that degree thread-safe.

Comment: The title question is "Are C# arrays thread safe". The first line of my answer explicates the thread safety of static and the lack of safety of instance members. Therefore arrays are not thread safe. Any other operations are not about thread safety of the array but rather about thread safety of whatever the array is stored in.

Comment: This MSDN documentation snippet is the same for just about any class in the .NET library, except for special classes like BlockingCollection. I think you miss the point in the question itself, where the asker wants to know whether _writing to elements in the array at a certain index, when no overlap occurs, is thread safe_. And the answer to that is: yes, they are thread safe, just don't write to the same index at the same time.

Comment: @Abel: Considering that I answered the question before the OP made the edit that specified how he's accessing the shared memory, I could only make a general answer based on the question title. Arrays are not, in general, thread safe. That was probably my line of thought when I wrote this. 

With 4.5 years of hindsight I'd say my answer isn't very good and like you say misses the point of the question (which again was very unclear when I answered it), but well, I don't really feel like putting in effort to fix it when the question has already received a better answer and the question is so old.

Answer (score 18):

Generally when a collection is said to be 'not threadsafe' that means that concurrent accesses could fail internally (e.g. it not safe to read the first element of List<T> while another thread adds an element at the end of the list: the List<T> might resize the underlying array and the read access might go to the new array before the data was copied into it).

Such errors are impossible with arrays because arrays are fixed-size and have no such 'structure changes'.
An array with three elements is no more or less thread-safe than three variables.

The C# specification doesn't say anything about this; but it is clear if you know IL and read the CLI specification - you could get a managed reference (like those used for C# "ref" parameters) to an element inside an array and then do both normal and volatile loads and stores to it. The CLI spec describes the thread-safety guarantees for such loads and stores (e.g. atomicity for elements <=32 bit)

So if I'm unterstanding your question correctly, you want to fill an array using different threads, but will assign to each array element only once? If so, that's perfectly thread-safe.

Answer (score 8):

The example you are providing is very similar to the way that Microsoft's own Parallel extensions to C# 4.0 work.

This for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
  a[i] = a[i]*a[i]; 
}
```

becomes

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, delegate(int i) { 
  a[i] = a[i]*a[i]; 
});
```

So, yes, your example should be OK.  Here's an older [blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) about the new parallel support in C#.