# What is the fast or proper way of parsing array in Parallel.For

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, parallel.for

I have a large single dimension array ful of Zmap data (ea height data)
the array is quite huge it consists of 100 measurements samples of an area pixel. I need to process it in several ways, so that another locked bitmap can be corrected. To speed up to processing of this large array I make use of parallel.for

ea:

```
public void MarkErrorSamples(int[]Depthdata,int lowbound)
{ 
    Parallel.For (0, depthData.Length, sampleN => 
    {
        if(depthData[sampleN] < lowbount) 
        {
            // update redchannel Red value by 20
            int x= xfromLockedmemPos(sampleN); // x value based upon sampleN
            int y =yfromLockedmemPos(sampleN); 
            setpixel(x,y,AddRed((getpixelRed(x,y),20);
        }
    });
}
```

The above code works but I have some doubts about accessing the `depthdata[sampleN]` the way I do it now. My concern here is that I think the threads might lock the array with each time a thread is launched to retrieve data from it. So I wonder is above the correct way to work with a 'external block' array data in an Parallel.for

Note that in the above void it is not required change the depthdata itself, only perform action on bitmap (making use of a lockbits bitmap).

Comment: _My concern here is that I think the threads might lock the array with each time a thread is launched to retrieve data from it_ Not sure if i get your sentence correctly but if the array gets locked for example  then this would not be parallel anymore.

Comment: The common consensus seems to be that accessing *different* parts of an array from different threads is not a problem. [Source 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2798899/87698), [Source 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1460660/87698).

Comment: @ M.kazem Yes i wonder that, nothing else is claiming the array when this function is called. but stll the elements of the array live outside the Parallel.Fro scope. So i wonder if its posible to put in each thread the valeu of depthData[sampleN]

Comment: Watch out for [`false sharing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) which may severely impact a parallel algorithm such as that because of forced processor cache reloads.

Comment: Ehm well yes i am woried about access locking , acoording to @Heinz its not a problem, while others write about it.
I might even 'batch' the whole dataset in smaller parts, and the let the simple actions run on smaller arrays.. but still i keep myself wondering about: memory locks,  arrays and threads.  And i dont know how to parse an array into a Parallel for, so that each thread knows which array element to use from scratch.