# Double checked locking in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, double-checked-locking

The idea is to get a value ("data") from

- a variable
- if doesn't exist, then from a file
- if doesn't exist, then from a server

```cs
public static string LoadData(int id)
{
    if (_isDataLoaded[id - 1])
    {
      return _data[id - 1];
    }

    if (File.Exists(_fileName))
    {
        bool dataExists;
        string cachedData;
        if (GetCachedConstant(id, out cachedData)) //read from a file
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                _isDataLoaded[id - 1] = true;
                _data[id - 1] = cachedData;
            }

            return _data[id - 1];
        }
    }

    string remoteData = GetFromServer(id);
    lock (_locker)
    {
        CacheToFile(id, remoteData); //write to a file
        _data[id - 1] = remoteData;
        _isDataLoaded[id - 1] = true;
    }

    return _data[id - 1];
}
```

This code is used by many threads. Although it seems to be thread safe, actually it isn't. I tested it, thus, that gives me that idea and makes me sure. There should be double check of existing `_data` before writing. For example, it should be like double check used in pattern Singleton usually.

Someone please let me understand how do I implement it here?

**EDIT:**

```
string[] _data;
bool[] _isDataLoaded.
```

**EDIT2**:

The code above might be used with .NET < 4.0, so it's not allowed to use Lasy there. The only question I have for now, is should I use volatile in case I would use double-checked locking?

```
volatile string[] _data;
volatile bool[] _isDataLoaded.
```

Comment: What about using the `Lazy<T>` class instead of implementing it yourself?

Comment: And what's the type of `_data`?

Comment: I'm assuming _locker is static?

Comment: @Alexandre `_data` is obviously not a string. It's some kind of collection that contains strings. But which collection?

Comment: Of course, that's string[].

Comment: Could you be optimizing prematurely? There could be other areas for optimization rather than lock contention.

Comment: @raymond, please explain in details.

Comment: @Alexandre Have you identified that it is locking contention among your threads that is causing bottleneck in your application? If you have not, you many want to profile you application first and see if you can optimize other areas, or identify that it is really locking contention that's causing bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two obvious sources of threading problems

- What type is `_data` and `_isDataLoaded`?  **If these types are not thread safe then neither is your code** [arrays are only thread safe if no two threads access the same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460634/are-c-sharp-arrays-thread-safe), which could happen in the above code.  Try using a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead.
- Depending on the exact implementation of `GetCachedConstant` and `CacheToFile` there is a potential race condition whereby thread A could begin writing cached data to a file causing thread B to go down the `File.Exists` route when in fact the file only contains partially written data

I'd guess the culprit is the first of these two - there might be other problems but unless these types are thread safe no amount of double checked locking will save you unless you also synchronize access to those objects.

Comment: string[] _data, bool[] _isDataLoaded.

Comment: @Alexandre Arrays are only thread safe if you can ensure that no two threads access the same element, which can happen in this case.  See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd replace `_data` with a `Lazy<string>[]`, where the fetching from file&network happens in the delegate you pass in.

So in the static constructor do something like:

```
_data=new Lazy<string>[maxId+1];
for(int i=0;i<_data.Length;i++)
{
  _data[i]=new Lazy<string>(()=>fetchData(i), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
}
```

and then to get the value simply `_data[i].Value`.

---

If you *really* want double checked locking, it basically works like this:

```
if (!_isDataLoaded[id - 1])
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        if(!_isDataLoaded[id - 1])
        {
            ...
            _data[id - 1] = ...;
            _isDataLoaded[id - 1] = true;
        }
    }
}
return _data[id - 1];
```

The problem with this code is that it's difficult to figure out if it's actually guaranteed to work. This depends on the memory model of the platform you're running on. AFAIK the .net 2.0 memory model guarantees that this works, but the ECMA CLR model and the java model don't. Memory model issues are very subtle and easy to get wrong. So I strongly recommend not using this pattern.

Comment: I don't want to use it, I want to understand how to work with double check. Lazy is an abstraction.

Comment: double locked is very subtle, and might break on some platforms. For example if you're using the EMCA memory model. I strongly recommend avoiding it, unless it's really necessary.

Comment: What if I would use Java, Ruby, C or something else? I think there is no Lazy there.

Comment: @Alexandre For each language/platform the answer is different, since each uses a different memory model. For example I'm not sure you can implement double checked locking in java, since their memory model is rather weak. As I said, double checked locking is subtle, and you need to know the memory model very well to be sure that it actually works reliably.

Comment: Thanks. But in case I would use double-checked locking, should I define data[] and dataLoaded as volatile?

Comment: An top on my question, what is fetchData()? It has to get the data from either a memory, a file or a server. So it will have to use lock anyway. Where is a benefit?

Comment: `fetchData` is the function which gets the information if it isn't loaded yet. In your case loading a file or downloading it. No matter which locking pattern you choose, it's a good idea to decouple the lazy/lock logic from the loading logic.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind double-check locking is in its name. You check your condition before `lock` (like in your code) but also inside the `lock` block again, to make sure that another thread didn't change the state (i.e. result of the condition) while the current thread was between the (successful) check and the `lock` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you lock at the beginning of the method. That assures you that your data (cache) will always be in a valid/consistent state.

Comment: Only when you're retrieving from file or from the server. In both cases, all threads would have to wait anyway.

Answer (score 1):

how about this, keep a single lock to load/persist data from/to the cache

```
public static string LoadData(int id)
{
    if (_isDataLoaded[id - 1])
      return _data[id - 1];

    lock (_locker)
    {
        if (_isDataLoaded[id - 1])
          return _data[id - 1];

        if (File.Exists(_fileName))
        {
            bool dataExists;
            string cachedData;
            if (GetCachedConstant(id, out cachedData)) //read from a file
            {
                _data[id - 1] = cachedData;
                _isDataLoaded[id - 1] = true;
                return _data[id - 1];
            }
        }

        string remoteData = GetFromServer(id);
        CacheToFile(id, remoteData); //write to a file
        _data[id - 1] = remoteData;
        _isDataLoaded[id - 1] = true;
        return _data[id - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove lock before CacheToFile?

Comment: because we already have a surrounding lock making sure that only one thread is allowed inside of that block at any given time.

Comment: Well, then why didn't you use lock at the beginning of the method? I assume it has to be there to ensure thread safe.

Comment: the read operations are thread safe, you only need the lock if you are going to alter the contents of the collections.

Answer (score 1):

```
    lock (_locker)
    {
        _isDataLoaded[id - 1] = true;
        _data[id - 1] = cachedData;
    }
```

Here `_isDataLoaded` is set before the `_data`, therefore there's a race with someone seeing `_isDataLoaded` and reading from `_data` before `_data` is initialized.

But reversing it does not solve the problem. There's no guarantee that another thread will see the assignments in the same order, because the reader does not use any lock nor memory barriers.

Check Wikipedia about proper way to do it with C#. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: I don't understand. There might be only one thread. Where is a problem?

Comment: First problem: one thread sets `_isDataLoaded[id-1]`. **Before** it sets `_data[id-1]` it gets preempted and another thread enters the method, sees `_isDataLoaded[id-1]` set and proceeds to access `_data[id-1]`, which is not yet initilized. Second problem: one thread sets `_data[id-1]` and `_isDataLoaded[id-1]` in that order, but another thread, on another processor, see the new value of `_isDataLoaded[id-1]`, but the old value of `_data[id-1]`.

Comment: All right. Then I could say `lock(...)` at the very beginning of LoadData() and there will be no issue, won't it (almost like @Christian Westerman said)?

Comment: Yes, but then you won't get the benefits of a (correctly implemented) double-checked locking.